# MySQL average and total

Tags: mysql, average

This is the code I have, but all values come out the same.

```
SELECT 
    department.name, 
    AVG(salary) AS Average, 
    SUM(salary) AS Total
FROM 
    department, employee
GROUP BY 
    department.name
```

[image: querie]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing a joining condition between the tables, so you're combining them as a full cross-product rather than linking the employees only to their departments.

```
SELECT d.name, AVG(e.salary), SUM(e.salary)
FROM department AS d
JOIN employee AS e ON d.dpt_no = e.dpt_no
GROUP BY d.name
```